# PHP SDK Lookup API and SMS Pricing

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-sdk

I would like to validate a phone number and get the price that it would cost to send a SMS to that phone number.

I can do this with 2 API calls, however according to https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/pricing you can do this with 1 call? "*Prices can be retrieved at a country level directly via the Pricing Messaging Countries resource `or for a specific phone number by leveraging the Lookup API and Pricing Messaging Countries resource.`*".

Am I overlooking something? or can this not be done?

Answer (score -1):

I'm Matt from Twilio's PHP content team. I've been looking through V2 of the Lookup API but don't see anything to do with it returning pricing information. That said, I'll take it up internally to find out more for you.